# Always return true when click on button when use jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery dialog box. When I click on Button popup is open but it return true and excute server side event of button.

I want when user clicks on yes then return true and else return false.

```
    function btnCancelClick()
            {
                $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 140,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function ()
                        {                       
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                  return true;
                        },
                        No: function ()
                        {                       
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                                return false;
                        }
                    }

                });             
            }

    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel Appointment" CssClass="cssbutton"
                                    OnClientClick="return btnCancelClick();" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** `return` from a dialog.

You have to use a callback function.

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Yes: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            clickedYes(); //YES CALLBACK
        },
        No: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            clickedNo(); //NO CALLBACK
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: clickedYes(); clickedNo(); not defined at all in javascript

Comment: shall i write return true and return false respectively for both method or what???

Comment: then what please elaborate ur  clickedYes clickedNo method

Comment: @John make functions that will be called when the user clicks on "Yes" or "No"

Comment: More accurately, the `dialog` method returns *immediately* (after creating the dialog and making it visible); by the time your yes/no callbacks run, you've *already* returned a value to the onclick handler, so "return whatever;" in the callbacks won't do what you think.  If you want to have a cancel-confirm, then you need to have the cancel-confirm functionality run when the appropriate button is clicked in the dialog, rather than relying on the cancel button's onclick or whatever to do it.

Comment: Neal i have make two function onclick of yes and no but doesnt work at all

Comment: chao@ ur right but how i handle this postback onclick of yes and do nothing onclick of no

Answer (score 1):

Update your `btnCancelClick` method to always return false. Then in the dialog button handlers, instead of return true or false do your postback right there.

```
function btnCancelClick() {
    $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                <%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnCancel, "")%>;
            },
            No: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This line:

`<%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnCancel, "")%>`

will register the javascript postback call into your `btnCancelClick` method.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that has a javascript alert where the ASP.NET postback would go: http://jsfiddle.net/GZFyz/1/

Comment: u add return false at the end of function it always return false doesnot postback

Comment: when add <%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnCancel, "")%>;
 generating error